# GRE Combinations Question with Restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am having trouble solving this problem from my GRE practice set:

A reading list for a humanities course consists of 10 books, of which 4 are
biographies and the rest are novels. Each student is required to read a
selection of 4 books from the list, including 2 or more biographies. How
many selections of 4 books satisfy the requirements?

I tried solving with (4*3*8*7)/4! but apparently that is incorrect.

Let me know if you can offer any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $3$ categories for the $4$ book choices.

$2B + 2N = \binom{4}{2}\cdot \binom{6}{2} = 90$

$3B + N = \binom{4}{3}\cdot 6 = 24$

$4B = 1$

Hence the number of selections is $115$